How do I change the underline color of mat-select in Angular 18?
I want to change the underline color(white) of mat-select if I hover it.
<h4>Basic native select</h4>
<mat-toolbar class="header">
<mat-form-field style="padding-top:20px">
<mat-label style="color:white">Choose an option</mat-label>
<mat-select>
    <mat-option value="option1">Option 1</mat-option>
 </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
</mat-toolbar>

I have the css like:
.mdc-line-ripple::after {
  transform: scaleX(1) !important;
  opacity: 1 !important;
}

demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/mpa36f-8pmwyn?file=src%2Fstyles.scss

Use the below CSS, which looks for hover of the form-field, then we set the color which should be the border-bottom-color.
.custom-hover-color:hover {
  .mdc-text-field--filled:not(.mdc-text-field--disabled)
    .mdc-line-ripple::after {
    border-bottom-color: red;
  }
}

Stackblitz Demo



/* Target the underline and change the color on hover */
.mat-form-field-underline {
  background-color: transparent; /* Default underline color */
}

.mat-form-field-underline:hover {
  background-color: white; /* Hover underline color */
}

/* Also change the color of the ripple when focusing or hovering */
.mat-form-field.mat-focused .mat-form-field-ripple,
.mat-form-field.mat-form-field-invalid .mat-form-field-ripple,
.mat-form-field:hover .mat-form-field-ripple {
  background-color: white; /* Ripple color when focused or hovered */
}
<h4>Basic native select</h4>
<mat-toolbar class="header">
  <mat-form-field style="padding-top: 20px">
    <mat-label style="color: white">Choose an option</mat-label>
    <mat-select>
      <mat-option value="option1">Option 1</mat-option>
    </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>
</mat-toolbar>



